# How to decode encode string in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am receiving below encoded string

```
"{\"type\":\"recipe\",\"id\":\"1624955566083\",\"entity\":\"loves\",\"count\":1}"
```

when i am doing like following it gives me undefined for each value. How can i generate JSON object from encoded string ?

```
const { type, id, entity, count } = JSON.parse(req.body);
console.log(type, id, entity); // All the values are undefined
```

Comment: Does [body-parser](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html) help here? `app.use(bodyParser.json())` ?

Comment: Please log `JSON.parse(req.body)` and add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have to do `JSON.parse(JSON.parse(req.body))` to make it work.